# displaying index page based on current year and quarter

Tags: php, date, dynamic, indexing

this is basically a followup from my previous question. My index page show the current year and quarter (eg: 2012 quarter 3, july, august, september) with all its contents. My problem might be simple to you but im a php noobie so im getting a hard time in figuring out the logic and how to do it. my pages are programmed dynamically in the sense that each data is stored in their proper month and year, my only problem is how to display dynamically the homepage based on the current quarter and year. thanks! This is my current code that i got from one of the answers in my previous question but it only changes the quarter dynamically.

```
if(!isset($_GET['quarter']) && !isset($_GET['year'])){
     $now   = new DateTime();
    $month = (int)$now->format("m");


    if ($month >= 1 AND $month <= 3) {
       include_once('/firstq2012.php');
    }
    elseif ($month >= 4 AND $month <= 6) {
        include_once('/secondq2012.php');
    }
    elseif ($month >= 7 AND $month <= 9) {
        include_once('/thirdq2012.php');
    }
    else {
        include_once('/fourthq2012.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you store your datas? and can you give me the format? I meant, is it an array or what?

Comment: not an array sir. every entry is input through a form with different fields

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!isset($_GET['quarter']) && !isset($_GET['year'])){
        $now   = new DateTime();
        $number_of_division_per_year = 4;//you can use 1,2,4,6,12
        $q = (($now->format("m")/($number_of_division_per_year-1))+1).'_';
         include_once('/'.$q.'2012.php');
         //now $q = 3(representing 3rd quarter);
         //your file names should be like this 1_2012.php(first quarter),
         //2_2012.php(second quarter) etc..
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to make it also show by year dynamically, you can do this :

```
if (!isset($_GET['quarter']) && !isset($_GET['year'])) {
    $now = new DateTime();
    $quarter = (int)$now->format('m')/4;
    $year = (int)$now->format('YYYY');
    $filename = '/'.$quarter.'-'.$year.'.php';
    include_once($filename);
}
```

But the filenames should be something like :

4-2011.php, 1-2012.php, 2-2012.php, 3-2012.php, 4-2012.php

Comment: actually sir, i dont have multiple files such as 1-2013.php, 1-2014.php. i only have one file per quarter and the content changes depending on the $_GET['year']. having multiple files would not make it dynamic though.

the "-2012" means nothing. its a usual filename. sorry for the confusion.